# VBA - Workbook Macro Pass Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an Excel file containing about 5 pages of vba code. All was good until,I choosen  to create a macro for the workbook for its protection. Something like.

`Dim pass as string/ 
if pass <> "PAR> or pass<>"par" then activeworkbook.close.`

I think that the `OR` messes the things up. Now I can't access my workbook. Whatever pass I introduced it closes the workbook. I may mention here that pass is an inputbox.

Can someone help me in resolving this problem. I've lost my entire work.

LE: i've made it! Thank you for your support! :)

Comment: first, please format you code, and provide more code example, where exactly is your issue and more information. But if you wana to open sheet without run macros, open with by Excel.exe with /s parameter

Comment: My workbook code looks like this:

Comment: Nothing..it does not work with shift. My entire code looks like this : Dim pass as Strig. If pass <> "vali" or pass<>"VALI" Then activeworbook.close. that's all. Usually i use Elseif but now i'used that silly OR.

Comment: I mention i've used Pass=inputbox. So everytime i open the workbook i get this box in which i am supposed to enter my pass.

Comment: and your code is in workbook open event?

Comment: Yes, it is. @Lubos

Comment: For the record - holding down SHIFT when opening a workbook makes Excel skip any `Auto_Open` or `Worbook_Open` event handlers from running in my environment (Excel 2010).

Comment: @Olle Sjögren that trick doesn't work in my Excel 2013!

Comment: OK! BTW, the `Or` in the code should have been `And`... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Sub main()

    Dim secAutomation As MsoAutomationSecurity

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Remember the macro security settings and disable macros in target workbook. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

    Workbooks.Open "<path to your workbook>"

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Reinstate previous macro security settings. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation

End Sub
```

or manually change your Macro settings to 'Disable all macros with notification'

Answer (score 0):

open any other workbook and get to the VBA IDE (ALT+F11)

type in Immediate Window

```
application.EnableEvents=False
```

then you can open your "impossible" workbook

as soon as you need things back regular type in the Immediate Window

```
application.EnableEvents=True
```

Comment: It does open but due to that inputbox i cannot access the vba in order to delete the workbook macro..

Comment: read carefully: you have to _first_ open _"any other workbook"_

Comment: This is what i'm doing. Open a blank workbook. Alt+f11 and write that statement. Keep this workbook open amd open the locked one.  The inputbox pop up and from that moment i cannot access anything.

Comment: my assumption is that the inputbox is popped out form inside the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`  event handler. If so, it _must_ work and I can only add that after typing `Application.EnableEvents=False` in the Immediate Window you must also press return...

Comment: @ValiGeorge did you get through it?

Comment: just to be sure you're making things right lets' make a simulation: 1) open a new workbook 2) jump to VBA IDE 3) doubleclick ThisWorkbook node in Project Window 4) Add some `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub` 5) save the workbook as worksheet with macro (name it "test") and close it 6) open another workbook 7) jump to VBA IDE 8) type `Application.EnableEvents=False` in the Immediate Window and press return key 9) now reopen the "test" workbook 10) there should not appear any "hello" messagbox. let me know

Comment: Yes. The message Hello pops up. :(

Comment: then it's really weird. Other than shutting down the PC and retrying you could still try to open the "impossible" workbook via a macro in any other workbook like `Sub main()
Dim wb As Workbook
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\myPath\myfilename.xlsm")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`

Comment: Using the same method as @user3598756 (in his previous comment) try replacing `Application.EnableEvents = False` with `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook cool. So let's wait for George's feedback. Meanwhile did you already met such a weird behavior of EnableEvents property? Why that?

Comment: It does not work. I think i will delete the file and im gonna try to rewrite the code. Thanky you guys for all your support and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: before deleting it you may want to upload with a link, together with a **big warning** about strange behaviour with it . should anybody attempt to open it to see what's happening in there...

Comment: All I can think is that the input box isn't being called using a macro - I haven't come across that problem before that disabling macros didn't fix. Maybe it's VSTO or some other way of programming Excel?

Comment: ok but the weirdest thing is that the "simulation" I proposed to George didn't work either. And that had to deal with brand new files only...

Comment: Sorry but i cannot upload the file. It is work related.

Comment: Don't feel sorry for me! I feel sorry for you loosing so much work! But before deleting it I'd suggest to try in another PC

Answer (score 0):

Try to open another workbook, and use `statement application.enableEvents = false` then before close this workbook, open workbook you wish

Comment: Sorry but i cannot upload the file. It is work related.

Comment: noone wana you to upload file. These are instructions to what can possibly help you

Comment: sorry, i've posted the upload related comment in the wrong section. Another user ask me if i could upload the file. Thx!