# Assigning priority to VBA Modules

Tags: excel, vba

I've written an excel macro that runs on a loop where it opens up a .xlsx file stored in a selected location, reads the value from a cell and saves the file in a different folder based on the cell value then moves on to the next file. The code works perfectly, but I have since had to add a macro that runs automatically when the .xlsx files are opened. Is there a way to set the priority of the various macros so that it doesn't run the macros from the .xlsx files when opened while the loop that opens and saves them is running?

lots of stack overflow threads and google searches later. I can find info on how to set the priority of items within the worksheet itself but nothing for the actual macros.

Comment: You can try to set a global variable in the workbooks you open by code. If the variable is set do not run the automatic macro on file open.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` will prevent that any event code (eg Workbook.Open) will be executed. Just don't forget to set it to True again.

Comment: "run the macros from the .xlsx files when opened" , you mean xlsm files. There is not "priority" of execution, but logic order, maybe via timers and a global variable in each of the xlsm files. Give us a skeleton of the macros you execute and from where initiate them, to help you.

Comment: The answer I gave here should help:  [VBA - Workbook Macro Pass Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456087/vba-workbook-macro-pass-error/37458819#37458819)